# how to retrieve echo data from php to jquery 1 by 1

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have a JQuery on click that sends a php query to MySql and then I want to send the data back 1 by 1 on JQuery.

But I only know how to send back results from php to JQuery as a whole.

my current JQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $(".img_thumb_holder").on("click", function() {
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "CMS/PHP/retrieveAuthorDetails.php",
        success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

my current php:

```
<?php
include 'dbAuthen.php';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE Name = 'james'";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo $row['UserID'];;
    echo $row['EmailAddr'];
}
?>
```

the outputs are both UserID and EmailAddr, I don't know how to just display either the UserID or EmailAddr out only

I tried alert(data[0]), but it only displayed one letter of the result.. Any ideas on how to do this?

UPDATE: After sean's help i have the current updated code

Jquery:

```
$(function() {
    $(".img_thumb_holder").on("click", function() {
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "CMS/PHP/retrieveAuthorDetails.php",
        success: function(data) {
                $.each(data, function() {
                    var userid = data.userid;
                    var useremail = data.email;
                    // i think there something wrong with this as it will keep repeating storing the userid and email for each data.. can someone verify?
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

PHP

```
<?php
include 'dbAuthen.php';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE Name = 'honwenhonwen'";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $arr = array(
        "userid" => "HonWen",
        "email" => "honwen@hotmail.com"
    );
}

echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

Comment: Use `json_encode()` and echo that. Jquery will recieve it as object.

Comment: Why not save your results in php as an array, then `json_ecode()` the array, then in your `$.ajax()` success you can loop through each array.

Comment: @sean i'm actually new to this, can u show me an simple example? I will go google about it too now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your php, save the results to an array -

```
<?php
include 'dbAuthen.php';
$array = array(); // create a blank array
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE Name = 'james'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    // add each result to the array
    $array[] = array('UserID'=> $row['UserID'], 'EmailAddr'=> $row['EmailAddr']);
}

echo json_encode($array); // json_encode() the array
?>
```

Then in your js/ajax you can loop through each value

```
$(function() {
    $(".img_thumb_holder").on("click", function() {
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "CMS/PHP/retrieveAuthorDetails.php",
          success: function(data) {
            // loop through each returned value
            $.each(data, function(){
                  //alert each result, this is just an example as alert() for each result is not a great idea
                  alert("UserID:"+ this.UserID + " EmailAddr:" + this.EmailAddr);
            });
          }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I think you should rather use `$.each(data, func)` rather than passing a bunch of data to the `$()` function itself. That's for DOM manipulation.

Comment: i actually managed to do it before your answer, can u advise if i'm doing right?

Answer (score 1):

jquery

```
$(function() {
        $(".img_thumb_holder").on("click", function() {
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "CMS/PHP/retrieveAuthorDetails.php",
            success: function(data) {
                    $.each(data, function() {
                        var userid = data.userid;
                        var useremail = data.email;
                        // i think there something wrong with this as it will keep repeating storing the userid and email for each data.. can someone verify?
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

php

```
<?php
include 'dbAuthen.php';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE Name = 'honwenhonwen'";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $arr = array(
        "userid" => "HonWen",
        "email" => "honwen@hotmail.com"
    );
}

echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

Comment: Is this your answer, or just your attempt? if just your attempt you should edit your question with this, not post as an answer. if this is your answer, there are a few issues.

Comment: (1) In you php, change `$arr = array("userid" => "HonWen","email" => "honwen@hotmail.com");` to `$arr[] = array("userid" => $row['UserID'],"email" => $row['EmailAddr']);`. (2) in your `$.ajax({ success: })` you need to do something with your `var userid` & `var useremail`. You could alert them, or `append()` them to a `div` or other element, etc.

Comment: yah just an attempt. Will do

Comment: @sean what if i want to just store the results from php to variable in jquery, if i use the each function, it will keep on repeating the storing per loop. How can i fix that? the stored variable are meant for later use, or it is ok to let it just repeat the storing per loop.

Comment: You don't have to loop through the results using `$.each()`. You could just store the results ie. `success: function(data) { var results = data;}`.

Comment: @sean haha yeah i just figured that out =P

Comment: @sean i realised that it work fine if i use $arr = array(
   "userid" => $row['UserID'],
   "email" => $row['EmailAddr']
  ); i echo alert(userid); smoothly but once i make it $arr[] = ... it alert 'undefined'

Comment: If you only have 1 row returned from your query, then `$arr = array(...` works. If you ever want to get more than 1 row, then you will need to use `$arr[] = array(...`

Comment: @sean, now i have a php that stores the different rows into array[] = $rows["link"], what is the code to display on jquery? i tried alert(data.array[0]), alert(data[0]). But doesn't work